# Java - AspectJ corrupted Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aspectj

I installed AJDT plugin from eclipse site. Then created Aspectj project. And if I saved anything in there, it started building workspace forever. I tried to close Eclipse, but needed to force close it and now it won't even starts, just loads forever. My code in project are only few lines, so I don't get it why it should be that slow. What could be wrong? Is AspectJ that slow or what?

How could I restore Eclipse as I can't even use it now..

**Update**
Eclipse loaded after like 10 minutes. Then I deleted one character of code and pressed save and it all started again. That is insane. I suppose it shouldn't be like that? I unchecked 'Build automatically' option, but it sill does the same thing.

And now I just got this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Compile error: OutOfMemoryError thrown: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

So it just ran out of memory. So it is something really wrong, but I don't see what could be.
Also this only happens with AspectJ project, with normal project everything runs smoothly. So maybe I should do something in AspectJ project before trying to write there, like check/uncheck something?

P.S. I also added Spring jars and commons-logging jars in that project. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: AspectJ is not that slow. Have you coded some Aspects? Can you show it, and also the Code it should advice? Aquick fi eclipce slow startup could be deleting the `workspace` folder, creating a fresh one once restarted and re-importing your projects. spring-jars or any other jars shouldnot cause any problems, just if you are going to use `AspectJ` so don't mix it with `Spring-AOP`.

Comment: Well I actually wanted to use Spring-AOP, but in Spring documentation it showed that they used aspectj. So I thought you need both. And didn't find anything to install for Spring AOP specific.

Comment: For spring you could use the [Spring tool suite](http://spring.io/tools/eclipse), you can install it either as plugin to your existing eclipse or get a bundle including eclipse from the spring site.

Comment: I have Spring already installed and I used it. But I don't understand if I need to somehow mix it with Aspectj as I see it depends on Aspectj. And if I create normal project, eclipse won't recognize '@Aspect' annotation or any other annotation for aspects.

Comment: Whyt do you mean by *Spring already installed*? It's just a couple of jars that you need  in the classpath of your project... Try to use Maven for managing them. Please see the [docs for spring-aop](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) and some other [online examples](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Comment: Well yes, I meant jars. I just have created my library with all Spring jars